# Jmockit, MOCKING METHODS

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, junit, mocking, jmockit

How do I mock the method `getProperty` using `JMockit`? Here is the code:

```
LWPropertyResource props = LWSupportFactoryImpl.getInstance().getPropertyResource(VALIDATE_HANDLER_PROPS);

String endDate = props.getProperty("endDate");
```

Comment: You should use `@Capturing` annotation, If `LWPropertyResource` is an interface. You may try this code `@Test
public void testMethod(@Capturing LWPropertyResource propsMocked)
{
 new Expectations()
 {
  {
   propsMocked.getProperty("endDate");
   retuns("someString");//You may return any string you want to return
  }
 }
 //Your test code
}`

Answer (score 1):

you need to mock the props class:

```
@Mocked LWPropertyResource props; //instance variable

new NonStrictExpectations {{
    props.getProperty("endDate"); result="My fake prop";
}};
```

Comment: The above way of mocking is not working.  private static LWPropertyResource props; so its static private field. I am using jmockit 1.8. I am surprised the above doesnt work. Pls can u provide any other way to sort it out ??.